# Having trouble reading this C# code

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth

I tried to modify the Wiimote Whiteboard app for my final project. But my experience in the C# is very little.
I found this code in EventArgs.cs
I do not know exactly what the code is doing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace WiimoteWhiteboard
{
    //??
    public class EventArgs<T> : EventArgs
    {
        public T Value
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public EventArgs(T value)
            : base()
        {
            Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a Generic EventArguments class with a get/set property. Which is likely used in a Event callback as a parameter.

Comment: You learn `C#` in few months ?? That's why you don't understand this code.Give it full year then Came and read again !!

Comment: @AshishMishra No need to be such an a*h*e about it, generic types are really hard to grasp at first so even a year might be not enough.

Comment: I am very sorry, it looks like I asking for the impossible. 
yes I was just learning C #, even without a tutor. only from a book that is intended for dummies. 
But I've been stuck in this situation. 
For that reason I joined this forum to look for someone who can guide me, than I learned without direction and purpose.
@AshishMisra

Comment: @user3332360 after you have understood this code passage a little better you could modify the title of your question to increase the informational content. So that people having the same problem can find this question and profit from the answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class EventArgs<T> : EventArgs
```

This is generic type class parameter `<T>` so you can create object of this class constrained to use specified type. You can use this type as placeholder, so you can have there integer or string so this class could operate on pretty much anything.

```
{
    public T Value
```

Here you use this generic type to specify type of Value property.
If you create object and pass generic type parameter this value can be only of type that you have passed when constructing object.
Mind that all this is done in compile time so it is not something dynamic, all types must be resolved by compiler at compile time.

```
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public EventArgs(T value)
```

Here is generic constructor, which you can invoke only with value of previously specified type so in place where you create object with `new` operator.

```
        : base()
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Jite mentioned in comments it might be used as parameter in Event callback which is another story and is not part of answer to your question.